# Change colors in 100% stacked barchart plotly python

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, bar-chart

I'm trying to change colors of stacked 100% barchart plot in plotly.

I have the following dataframe and code:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly
import plotly.express as px
from plotly.offline import plot

df = pd.DataFrame([["A", "Jan", "20%"],
                   ["A", "Fev", "10%"],
                   ["A", "Mar", "15%"],
                   ["A", "Apr", "10%"],
                   ["B", "Jan", "15%"],
                   ["B", "Fev", "15%"],
                   ["B", "Mar", "20%"],
                   ["B", "Apr", "10%"],
                   ["C", "Jan", "25%"],
                   ["C", "Fev", "25%"],
                   ["C", "Mar", "20%"],
                   ["C", "Apr", "30%"],
                   ["D", "Jan", "40%"],
                   ["D", "Fev", "50%"],
                   ["D", "Mar", "45%"],
                   ["D", "Apr", "50%"]],
                  columns=["type", "month", "percentage"])

colors = plotly.colors.qualitative.Prism

fig=px.bar(df, x='month', y='percentage',
            color=df['type'], barmode ='stack', 
            text = df['percentage'])


fig.update_traces(textfont_size=12, marker_color = colors)

fig.update_layout(title = {'text': "Title",
                           'x':0.5, 'xanchor': 'center'},
                  title_font_size=30,
                  legend=dict(yanchor="bottom", y=0.0, 
                              xanchor="right", x=1.2),
                  legend_font_size=16, 
                  xaxis_title = 'Months', 
                  yaxis_title ='%',
                  xaxis_tickangle=-45,
                  width = 1000, height = 600)
fig.show()
```

But I'm getting the following:
[image: Stacked barchart-wrong colored]

Changing the colors of the whole bars, instead of change the colors for each section of the bars.

What I want is to change the blue, red, green, purple from the original one:

[image: Stacked barchart-original]

(That is what I get when there's no `marker_color = colors` in `fig.update_traces`, trying to change the colors as I want.)

How can I do it properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the [`color_discrete_sequence`](https://plotly.com/python/discrete-color/) argument of [`px.bar`](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.express.bar) instead of `marker_color` in `update_traces`:

```
colors = plotly.colors.qualitative.Prism

fig = px.bar(df, x='month', y='percentage',
             color=df['type'], barmode='stack',
             text=df['percentage'].astype(str) + '%',  # Add Percent Sign
             color_discrete_sequence=colors)

# Don't forget to remove from update_traces
fig.update_traces(textfont_size=12)
```

[image: styled plot]

Data and Imports (removed string percentages as they were not plotting correctly):

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame([["A", "Jan", 20],
                   ["A", "Fev", 10],
                   ["A", "Mar", 15],
                   ["A", "Apr", 10],
                   ["B", "Jan", 15],
                   ["B", "Fev", 15],
                   ["B", "Mar", 20],
                   ["B", "Apr", 10],
                   ["C", "Jan", 25],
                   ["C", "Fev", 25],
                   ["C", "Mar", 20],
                   ["C", "Apr", 30],
                   ["D", "Jan", 40],
                   ["D", "Fev", 50],
                   ["D", "Mar", 45],
                   ["D", "Apr", 50]],
                  columns=["type", "month", "percentage"])
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Henry Ecker! I had an update for plotly and suddenly the percentages were not plottling correctly (not having the total 100% per bar). I'll try this approach.